# Calculation of Approximate Equation with Mathematica

Tags: simplifying-expressions, approximation

I am trying to find an approximate equation for a complicated expression (L1, L2) using Mathematica. The equation involves several parameters and expressions, and I want to simplify it by considering the following approximations: k << 1, Ns << 1, and Nb >> 1

```
S = 2 Ns + 1
B = 2 Nb + 1
A = 2*k*Ns + B
Cq = 2*Sqrt[Ns*(Ns + 1)]
vH1[i_] = ((-1)^i*(S - A) + Sqrt[(A + S)^2 - 4*k*(Cq)^2])/2
L[s_, x_] = ((x + 1)^s + (x - 1)^s)/((x + 1)^s - (x - 1)^s)
L1 = L[1/2, vH1[1]] // Simplify
L2 = L[1/2, vH1[2]] // Simplify
```

$$L1=-\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{(k \text{Ns}+\text{Nb}+\text{Ns}+1)^2-4 k \text{Ns} (\text{Ns}+1)}+k \text{Ns}+\text{Nb}-\text{Ns}-1}+\sqrt{\sqrt{(k \text{Ns}+\text{Nb}+\text{Ns}+1)^2-4 k \text{Ns} (\text{Ns}+1)}+k \text{Ns}+\text{Nb}-\text{Ns}+1}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{(k \text{Ns}+\text{Nb}+\text{Ns}+1)^2-4 k \text{Ns} (\text{Ns}+1)}+k \text{Ns}+\text{Nb}-\text{Ns}-1}-\sqrt{\sqrt{(k \text{Ns}+\text{Nb}+\text{Ns}+1)^2-4 k \text{Ns} (\text{Ns}+1)}+k \text{Ns}+\text{Nb}-\text{Ns}+1}}$$

$$L2=-\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{(k \text{Ns}+\text{Nb}+\text{Ns}+1)^2-4 k \text{Ns} (\text{Ns}+1)}-k \text{Ns}-\text{Nb}+\text{Ns}-1}+\sqrt{\sqrt{(k \text{Ns}+\text{Nb}+\text{Ns}+1)^2-4 k \text{Ns} (\text{Ns}+1)}-k \text{Ns}-\text{Nb}+\text{Ns}+1}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{(k \text{Ns}+\text{Nb}+\text{Ns}+1)^2-4 k \text{Ns} (\text{Ns}+1)}-k \text{Ns}-\text{Nb}+\text{Ns}-1}-\sqrt{\sqrt{(k \text{Ns}+\text{Nb}+\text{Ns}+1)^2-4 k \text{Ns} (\text{Ns}+1)}-k \text{Ns}-\text{Nb}+\text{Ns}+1}}$$

I would like the approximate equations for L1 and L2 to give the values 81.9882 and 1.22094, respectively, when k=0.01, Ns=0.01, Nb=20.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You could try an expansion with `Series`.

Comment: Your definitions of `L1,L2` depend on `A,S,k,Cq`! Please correct your question

Comment: @Ulrich Neuman:  Apologies, I forgot to include the definitions of A, S, B, and Cq in the question. Now, I have updated question.

Comment: @SumitSugar Thanks for the update. What is known about the limiting behavior of the three parameters?  Perhaps `Nb~1/eps,k~eps, Ns~eps as eps->0`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: the limiting behaviour of the three parameters (Nb, k, and Ns) as epsilon (eps) approaches 0. It's worth considering these limits to see if they provide valuable insights into the approximate equation. The values of the three parameters (Nb, k, and Ns) can be in the range of: Ns=0.01-0.1, k=0.01-0.5, and Nb=10-100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may expand L1 and L2 in a series around k==0, Ns==0 and Nb around infinity like:

```
ser1= Series[L1, {k, 0, 1}, {Ns, 0, 1}, {Nb, Infinity, 1}] // Normal

2 - 1/(4 Nb) + 4 Nb + k (4 - 4/Nb) Ns

ser2=Series[L2, {k, 0, 1}, {Ns, 0, 1}, {Nb, Infinity, 1}] // Normal

1 + 2 Sqrt[Ns] + 2 Ns + k (-(Sqrt[Ns]/Nb) - (2 Ns)/Nb)
```

Now to test:

```
{ser1, ser2} /. { k -> 0.01, Ns -> 0.01, Nb -> 20}

{81.9879, 1.21994}
```

Comment: @Deniel Huber: Thank you very much for helping me with the problem!

Answer (score 0):

If the asymptotic behavior of the parameters is `Nb~1/eps,k~eps, Ns~eps as eps->0` try

```
Asymptotic[L1 /. {Nb -> Nb/eps, k -> eps k, Ns -> eps Ns}, {eps, 0, 2}] /.eps -> 1 // Simplify[#, Nb > 0] &
(*2 + 1/(8 Nb^2) - 1/(4 Nb) + 4 Nb + 4 k Ns*)
```

Unfortuantely the same procedure applied to `L2` gives a message "Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0^2 encountered."

Comment: Thank you for your valuable contributions and efforts.